# Best practice to have an empty element or create a new fragment?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it better to have a div with some empty p tags that you can query and fill up with text OR is it better to not have any p tags in the div and if you need them, you create them with the text?

Does the decision metter if you have 1-3 divs or if you have 100 of them?
In the worst case their will be allot of unused p tags with no text.

Comment: In my opinion you should create them dynamically. But it comes down to each individual case what's "better".

Comment: Typically speaking, if you're relying on JS to populate the page with data, then also rely on JS to populate your page with the templates for that data. That could be through a template system, it could be through pushing things into a `documentFragment`, it could be through building view-specific functions like `buildTweet`, or it could be through saving a single templated version of what you want, cloning that template, and then using selectors (or a text-parser, or whatever) to insert the data.

Comment: You shouldn't really have any empty mark up at all in a webpage

Comment: Ok! Thanks guys, ill go with adding the tags dynamically.